# Mount partition by using LiveCD

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am a newbie in Ubuntu / Linux. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my PC and made partitions using Gparted in LiveCD, but I could not access `/dev/sda3`. I want to move the home folder to `/dev/sda3`.

`lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0 388.9G  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0    73G  0 part /
```

`blkid`:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="d5af258a-cc7e-4499-b2ba-4baeaa56e6ab" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d90431dc-01"
/dev/sda3: UUID="d29f4787-8c86-41b8-a065-77640dfeec8a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d90431dc-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="692050b9-368e-4244-bbf6-b5bf33bbc78e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d90431dc-05"
```

`mount`:

```
$ sudo mount -l
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=2003552k,nr_inodes=203387,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404748k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=24,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=653)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404748k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

`udisksctl`:

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda3
Mounted /dev/sda3 at /media/abadium/d29f4787-8c86-41b8-a065-77640dfeec8a.
```

`/proc/mounts`:

```
$ awk '$1=="/dev/sda3"' /proc/mounts
/dev/sda3 /media/abadium/d29f4787-8c86-41b8-a065-77640dfeec8a ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

`dmesg`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 30
[ 3563.641071] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3566.455588] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3570.006201] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3577.615223] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3580.628799] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3618.257708] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3708.624004] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3711.097156] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3714.622100] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3722.255348] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3725.265693] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3949.281166] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3956.183980] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3958.706005] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3962.307873] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3969.860456] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 3972.815333] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 3986.866669] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 4248.047985] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 4250.866754] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 4254.486597] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 4262.032993] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 4265.098635] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 6216.708575] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 6425.007831] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 6427.675873] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 6431.194721] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 6438.842953] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 6441.712442] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[ 8310.625855] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: Please, attach the output of `sudo mount -l`

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda3`? If it succeeds also include the output of `awk '$1=="/dev/sda3"' /proc/mounts`; if it fails include `sudo dmesg | tail -n 30`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for editing the output of those command into your original question. The `udisksctl` command line was successful, and mounted `/dev/sda3` at `/media/abadium/d29f4787-8c86-41b8-a065-77640dfeec8a`. So now you have access to it (you can change directory in a terminal window to the mountpoint or browse via your file browser). Let us know, if you can do what you need now, or if you need more help :-)

Comment: I am really sorry, I still couldn't access the/dev/sda3 from file browser. I tried to open Libreoffice Writer and then save a file to the /dev/sda3 and still couldn't saving file to dev/sda3. I am really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Mounting

- You can mount it temporarily from the live DVD with the following command

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
  ```
- Mount it automatically in the installed system via a line in the file `/etc/fstab`. Edit it with

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```

  - You must find the UUID of the partition and use it in **`/etc/fstab`**. See the output of

    ```
    sudo blkid
    ```

    and use it (without quotes).
  - You must replace `/` with `/home`, and replace the `1` with `2` at the end of the line, otherwise the line can look like the line for the root partition, so you can copy that line and edit it. See more details in the manual

    ```
    man fstab
    ```
  - ***Wait* until you have copied the files to the new location.** Do not do this now.

### 2. Copying

You can copy the content of the `/home` directory to the new location with the following command,

```
sudo rsync -Havn /path-to-old-home/ /path-to-new-home
```

when the partitions of both are mounted. This is 'dry run' and will only show what will be copied. Please notice the trailing slash in `/path-to-old-home/` as described in `man rsync`. A trailing slash has a special meaning in an rsync command line, to copy the *content* of the source directory, not the source directory itself.

If you do it in the installed system, you must mount `/dev/sdx3`, where `x` is probably `a` (no longer `b`), but check and modify it.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdx3 /mnt
```

and you can try with

```
sudo rsync -Havn /home/ /mnt
```

Anyway, when you are ready to do the real copying, remove the letter `n`

```
sudo rsync -Hav /path-to-old-home/ /path-to-new-home
```

or

```
sudo rsync -Hav /home/ /mnt
```

After the copying you can run the rsync command line once again, and it should be happy and not suggest any more copying. When you have checked like that,

- you can remove the files from the old home location, and
- prepare for mounting via **`/etc/fstab`** (as described previously).
- and reboot into the system.

Now the installed system should use `/dev/sdx3` for `/home`.